# Create a route identifier from timestamps

Tags: python, datetime, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, pyspark

I have data from a telematics device with a driver ID, a timestamp and some sensor data which are not relevant for my example.

I want to create a route identifier and a record counter from this data in order to calculate statistics for each route for each driver. We are using pyspark 1.2.1 on a YARN cluster from the Hortonworks HDP 2.2.6.0 platform.

My data looks like this, it is in a pair RDD and these two elements are the key:

```
| driverID | timestamp |  
| D1        | 1         |  
| D1        | 2         |  
| D1        | 6         |  
| D1        | 8         |  
| D2        | 1         |  
| D2        | 3         |  
| D2        | 4         |  
| D2        | 7         |
```

I want to get the runID and sequenceID column, with the hypothesis that a lag of 3 time units starts a new run

```
| driverID | timestamp | runID | sequenceID  
| D1        | 1         | 1     |1  
| D1        | 2         | 1     |2  
| D1        | 6         | 2     |1  
| D1        | 8         | 2     |2  
| D2        | 1         | 1     |1  
| D2        | 3         | 1     |2  
| D2        | 4         | 1     |3  
| D2        | 7         | 2     |1
```

What would you suggest me to do ? This will be used ultimately with a terabyte size dataset. Driver ID is a string and timestamp is actually a datetime object.

thanks for your help